# Batch modify files Haskell

Tags: file, haskell, io

I am trying to create a program that adds a simple text header to every file in a directory (and its subdirectories). I need to do this just using the built in functions from ghc (I can't access cabal).

The type signature of the functions are

```
getRecursiveContents :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]

addHeaderToFile :: String -> FilePath -> IO ()
```

These both work fine independently but I am struggling to use the two functions in conjunction because of the types. I assumed using a map would be the correct way to do this, but so far I have been unsuccessful.

```
addHeaderToMultiple :: String -> IO [FilePath] -> IO ()
addHeaderToMultiple header files = map (addHeaderToFile header) files
```

I understand this will not work due to the types used but I have not found a way to fix it.

Comment: Have a look at `mapM_ :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m ()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by running the IO action producing the file list:

```
addHeaderToMultiple :: String -> IO [FilePath] -> IO ()
addHeaderToMultiple header files = do
   -- files has type IO [FilePath]
   paths <- files
   -- paths has type [FilePath], so we can map over that
   map (addHeaderToFile header) paths
   -- this produces [IO ()], which is not IO ()
```

We hit a problem in the last line, which builds a list of IO actions instead of running them. We could use a helper function:

```
runInSequence :: [IO ()] -> IO ()
runInSequence []     = return ()  -- nothing to do
runInSequence (a:as) = a >> runInSequence as
```

which can be simplified to

```
runInSequence = foldr (>>) (return ())
```

Actually, there already exists a library function doing that: it's called `sequence_`. Our code now becomes

```
import Control.Monad
addHeaderToMultiple header files = do
   paths <- files
   sequence_ (map (addHeaderToFile header) paths)
   -- this produces IO (), so it's OK
```

The combo `sequence_ (map ...` has its own library function as well, called `mapM_`:

```
addHeaderToMultiple header files = do
   paths <- files
   mapM_ (addHeaderToFile header) paths
```

This can be further refined using `>>=` directly

```
addHeaderToMultiple header files =
   files >>= mapM_ (addHeaderToFile header)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly and thanks for explaining the steps along the way too, it made it much easier to understand.